# Does Spark respect kudu's hash partitioning similar to bucketed joins on parquet tables?

Tags: apache-spark, kudu, apache-kudu

I'm trying out Kudu with Spark. I want to join 2 tables with the following schema-

```
# This table has around 1 million records
TABLE dimensions (
    id INT32 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
HASH (id) PARTITIONS 32,
RANGE (id) (
    PARTITION UNBOUNDED
)
OWNER root
REPLICAS 1

# This table has 500 million records
TABLE facts (
    id INT32 NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, date)
)
HASH (id) PARTITIONS 32,
RANGE (id, date) (
    PARTITION UNBOUNDED
)
OWNER root
REPLICAS 1
```

I inserted data to these tables using the following script-

```scala
// Load data to spark dataframe
val dimensions_raw = spark.sqlContext.read.format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("/root/dimensions.csv")

dimensions_raw.printSchema
dimensions_raw.createOrReplaceTempView("dimensions_raw")

// Set the primary key columns
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def setNotNull(df: DataFrame, columns: Seq[String]) : DataFrame = {
  val schema = df.schema
  // Modify [[StructField] for the specified columns.
  val newSchema = StructType(schema.map {
    case StructField(c, t, _, m) if columns.contains(c) => StructField(c, t, nullable = false, m)
    case y: StructField => y
  })
  // Apply new schema to the DataFrame
  df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, newSchema)
}
val primaryKeyCols = Seq("id") // `primaryKeyCols` for `facts` table is `(id, date)`
val dimensions_prep = setNotNull(dimensions_raw, primaryKeyCols)
dimensions_prep.printSchema
dimensions_prep.createOrReplaceTempView("dimensions_prep")


// Create a kudu table
import collection.JavaConverters._
import org.apache.kudu.client._
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
val kuduContext = new KuduContext("localhost:7051", spark.sparkContext)

// Delete the table if it already exists.
if(kuduContext.tableExists("dimensions")) {
    kuduContext.deleteTable("dimensions")
}

kuduContext.createTable("dimensions", dimensions_prep.schema,
  /* primary key */ primaryKeyCols,
  new CreateTableOptions()
    .setNumReplicas(1)
    .addHashPartitions(List("id").asJava, 32))

// Load the kudu table from spark dataframe
kuduContext.insertRows(dimensions_prep, "dimensions")
// Create a DataFrame that points to the Kudu table we want to query.
val dimensions = spark.read
    .option("kudu.master", "localhost:7051")
    .option("kudu.table", "dimensions")
    .format("kudu").load
dimensions.createOrReplaceTempView("dimensions")
```

Ran the above script for `facts` table as well.

I want to join `facts` with `dimensions` table on `id`. I tried the following command in Spark-

```scala
val query = facts.join(dimensions, facts.col("id") === dimensions.col("id"))
query.show()

// And I get the following Physical plan-
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) SortMergeJoin [id#0], [id#14], Inner
:- *(2) Sort [id#0 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0, 200), true, [id=#43]
:     +- *(1) Scan Kudu facts [id#0,date#1] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int,date:date...
+- *(4) Sort [id#14 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#14, 200), true, [id=#49]
      +- *(3) Scan Kudu dimensions [id#14] PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<id:int>
```

My question is that how do I tell spark that the tables are already sorted on `id` (join key) so no need to sort again.
Moreover the `Exchange hashpartitioning` need not be done as the table is already bucketed over `id`.

The join query is taking sub 100seconds on a single machine with single master & tablet server running.
Am I doing something wrong here or is it the expected speed with Kudu for this kind of query?